# jQuery submenu won't show up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Using the following code I could get the ABOUT and FAQ submenus to show up but nothing would appear on mouse hover and I have no idea why. Please help! If there is more code I should show just let me know! Thanks in advance for any help :)

The HTML:

```
 <ul class="navigation">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Gallery Tour</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>

                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Accomodations</a></li>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Event Space</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Guest Rooms</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Kitchen and Catering Facility</a></li>
                </ul>           
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Activities</a></li>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">The Katy Trail</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Augusta</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">St. Louis Attractions</a></li>
                </ul>
            <li><a href="#">Reservations</a></li>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Rates</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Request Info</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Event Agreement Form</a></li>
                 </ul>
                    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Additional Info</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Catering</a></li>
                </ul>
</ul>
```

The CSS:

```
.navigation  {margin:0; padding:0;list-style:none;  }   


    .navigation  li {
        float:left;         
        width:120px; 
        position:relative; 
    }


    .navigation  li a {
        background:#262626; 
        color:#fff;
        display:block;      
        padding:8px 7px 8px 7px; 
        text-decoration:none; 
        border-top:1px solid #F2861D;
        text-align:center; 
        text-transform:uppercase;
    }

    .navigation  li a:hover {
        color:#F2861D;
    }


    .navigation  ul {
        position:absolute; 
        left:0; 
        display:none; 
        margin:0 0 0 -1px; 
        padding:0; 
        list-style:none;
        border-bottom:3px solid #F2861D;
    }

    .navigation  ul li {
        width:150px; 
        float:left; 
        border-top:none;
        overflow: visible;
    }


    .navigation  ul a {
        display:block;      
        height:15px;
        padding:8px 7px 13px 7px; 
        color:#fff;
        text-decoration:none;   
        border-top:none;
        border-bottom:1px dashed #6B6B6B;
    }

    .navigation  ul a:hover {
        color:#F2861D;
    }`
```

The Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Navigation function
    $('.navigation li').hover(function () {
            $('ul', this).fadeIn();
    },
    function () {$('ul', this).fadeOut();}
    );
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/py5UQ/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `li` elements for Accommodations, Activities and Reservations didn't correctly nest the submenu's `ul` elements. Check out the code in this JS Fiddle for a corrected version:

http://jsfiddle.net/9NdZC/

Here is just the HTML part:

```
<ul class="navigation">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Gallery Tour</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>

            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Accomodations</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Event Space</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Guest Rooms</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Kitchen and Catering Facility</a></li>
            </ul>           
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Activities</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">The Katy Trail</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Augusta</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">St. Louis Attractions</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Reservations</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Rates</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Request Info</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Event Agreement Form</a></li>
             </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#">FAQ</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Additional Info</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Catering</a></li>
            </ul>
           </li>
     </ul>
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Would you mind accepting my answer? Thanks!